# Installing tensorflow object detection API on Windows 11, stuck on installation of pycocotools

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I'm installing tensorflow object detection API on Windows 11, however I'm stuck on the installation of pycocotools.

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbBgD.png)I'm following the tutorial on https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-installation however I keep getting errors.

The command that is giving me errors is pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI

Please check the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqhyf.png) it has a screenshot of the errors

Comment: If you can include the key parts of the error message as text in the body of your question, that will help people find this question and hopefully answer it.  I appreciate there are a lot of details in the error message, so keeping the screenshot of the full error is good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `basetsd.h` file is missing. Try to download and install `Windows 11 SDK` from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/). If you have it installed already, check if windows SDK and the Microsoft Visual C++ are added to system PATH, if not adding them to system PATH will help.

As you already have Visual Studio compiler, you will need to install only **Developer Tools > Windows Headers and Libraries**, which includes missing `basetsd.h`. Thanks!